# How do I test if a primitive in Objective-C is nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, primitive

I'm doing a check in an iPhone application -

```
int var;
if (var != nil)
```

It works, but in X-Code this is generating a warning "comparison between pointer and integer." How do I fix it?

I come from the Java world, where I'm pretty sure the above statement would fail on compliation.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Primitives can't be `nil`.  `nil` is reserved for pointers to Objective-C objects.  `nil` is technically a pointer type, and mixing pointers and integers will without a cast will almost always result in a compiler warning, with one exception: it's perfectly ok to implicitly convert the integer 0 to a pointer without a cast.

If you want to distinguish between 0 and "no value", use the [`NSNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class:

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
if(num == nil)  // compare against nil
    ;  // do one thing
else if([num intValue] == 0)  // compare against 0
    ;  // do another thing
```

Answer (score 11):

```
if (var) {
    ...
}
```

Welcome to the wonderful world of C. Any value not equal to the integer 0 or a null pointer is true.

**But you have a bug: ints cannot be null. They're value types just like in Java.**

If you want to "box" the integer, then you need to ask it for its address:

```
int can_never_be_null = 42; // int in Java
int *can_be_null = &can_never_be_null; // Integer in Java
*can_be_null = 0; // Integer.set or whatever
can_be_null = 0;  // This is setting "the box" to null,
                  //  NOT setting the integer value
```

Comment: everything does seem to work though, where is a case where this would give me problems?

just for some background - "var" is a property in a Domain Object. In one of my ViewControllers, I have a UISegmentedViewController that is used to set the value of "var." So, before the user selects anything, var has not yet been set.

Comment: var == 0 if it has not yet been set

Comment: Sure it has been set - it's been set to an undefined value. ints can *only* take on integral values. You should be comparing against 0 or you should use a separate BOOL flag to determine/designate whether `var` is valid.