# Filtering values with NSNumber == nil in NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm trying select values by property with type NSNumber, if property==intValue or property==nil.
But this code ignores values with property==nil.
What the point?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"(ANY region.beacons.major == %d OR ANY region.beacons.major = nil) 
        AND (ANY region.beacons.minor == %d OR ANY region.beacons.minor = nil)",
        rangedBeacon.major.intValue, rangedBeacon.minor.intValue];
```

[image]

UPD: The most simple doesn't work too:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                               @"ANY region.beacons.minor = nil"];
```

UPD 2: Probably problem because of ANY+nil
According to this answer [Core Data, NSPredicate, ANY key.path == nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193872/core-data-nspredicate-any-key-path-nil) ANY select only NOTNULL values.

Comment: Why duplicate? I don't understand the `uint16_t` stuff, since it's not a object, it shouldn't be nil. Why isn't it a `NSNumber`? Aren't you using `CLBeacon` objects?

Comment: I duplicated this question, because brevios marked as duplicated now and linked on wrong answer. Yes, I'm using CLBeacon.

Comment: Well, according to linked answer, you should write `nil` and not `NIL` anyways in your predicate, modification that your code doesn't reflect. Now, what about the other questions I asked in my previous comment?

Comment: Larme, sorry, I copipasted previous question in hurry. I corrected NIL into nil and this did not help.

Comment: What was wrong with the duplicate question's answers? The code you've posted here is not how it is shown in the answers of the duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: rmaddy, thous answer doesn't solve my problem

Comment: As stated before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895495/how-do-i-test-if-a-primitive-in-objective-c-is-nil I still don't understand why `minor` a `uint16_t`, whereas it should be a `NSNumber`, and why it `major` is a `NSNumber`?

Comment: It's my fault again. I thought that property value the same type as parameter value in initialization. Yes, it's NSNumber.

Answer (score 0):

Simply test for one of the properties of minor; for example:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                           @"region.beacons.minor.length = 0"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                           @"region.beacons.minor.stringValue = nil"];
```

**EDIT** I recognized, that you should remove the `ANY`

If `minor` is nil, any call would return in nil as well, or 0 for numeric types.

Answer (score -1):

For one thing, I notice you're using the **assignment** operator `=` instead of **equality** `==` while comparing with `nil`.

Also, try comparing with the Singleton NSNull instance `[NSNull null]`.

Comment: In predicates, `=` is not an assignment.